# How to hide the bottom info panel (status bar) in the Brackets editor?

Tags: settings, adobe-brackets

Is possible to hide the bottom panel in Brackets? The one with lines and columns on the left and possible error messages, the language and some other details on the right.

I really like the Brackets code editor but unfortunately I have to work on a rather small screen and the bottom panel wastes valuable space without being useful to me.

I checked in the preferences of Brackets and in the official documentation, but there seems to be nothing on it.

Does anyone know if it is possible to hide the info panel?

Answer (score 1):

The bottom panel is called the *status bar*. It appears there isn't a feature that allows you to hide or toggle it yet, but you could try submitting an issue in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues).

If you really can't wait and don't mind getting your hands dirty, you can hit F12 to open the Developer Tools, pick the status bar, and change `display: block` to `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could make the change more permanently - without having to edit the source code directly or write your own extension from scratch:

1. Install the extension ["Brackets UI Custom CSS"](https://github.com/tobibeer/brackets-custom-css)
2. Edit the *styles.css* file the extension provides (see instructions in link above)
3. Add `#status-bar { display: none; }` to the CSS & restart Brackets